# How do I change the values of an multidimension array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve this problem, I have already tried some things that I know of but it doesn't work. I believe it's the if statement that I'm not doing right. Can somebody give me a light?

```
var numbers = [
  [ 1,2,3],
  [ 4,5,6],
  [ 7,8,9]];

for(var row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for(var column = 0; column < numbers[row].length; column++){
        if(numbers[row].length % 2 === 0){
            numbers[row][column] = "even";
        }else{
            numbers[row][column] = "odd";
        }
        console.log(numbers[row][column]);
    }
}
```

I expect the array numbers have the elements changed for "even" and "odd".

Comment: In your modulus, don't you want `if(numbers[row][column] %2 === 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var numbers = [
  [ 1,2,3],
  [ 4,5,6],
  [ 7,8,9]];

for(var row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++){
    for(var column = 0; column < numbers[row].length; column++){
    
        console.log(numbers[row][column]  %2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate `numbers[row].length % 2 === 0` is checking if the row has an even number of elements. I assume what you want is `numbers[row][column] % 2 === 0`.

Comment: I knew it I was doing the If statement wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result array to look something like this

```
[
   ["odd", "even", "odd"],
   etc...
]
```

Then your if statement is missing the column argument

```
if(numbers[row][column] % 2 === 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [
  [ 1,2,3],
  [ 4,5,6],
  [ 7,8,9]
];


 for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++){
        if (numbers[i][j] % 2 !== 0) {
            numbers[i][j] = "odd"
        } else{
            numbers[i][j] = 'even'
        }
    }
 }
```

In your conditional, you are asking if the length of the element is divisible by 2, when it should be the element itself.  Remember, you are already in your nested loop at that point of your algorithm, so you are displaying only the numbers inside the nested arrays and not the arrays themselves.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't know.